# How to select a column name with a space in Jupiter using PostgreSQL and %sql magic?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter, psycopg2

I'm trying to select some columns with spaces in their names. I'm using sqlalchemy and postgresql + psycopg2 in Jupiter. When I create an engine everything works fine:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Employee Number" = 1103024456')
```

I want to use sql magic in Jupiter, and this code for example works fine:

```
%load_ext sql
%sql postgresql+psycopg2://readonly:***@dsstudents.skillbox.ru:5432/human_resources

%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE id = 1
```

but when column names contain spaces, syntax error occurs. I tried to use quotes, backticks, apostrophes, brackets, also added table name, tried different combinations:

```
%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Employee Number" = 1103024456

%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE 'Employee Number' = 1103024456

%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE [Employee Number] = 1103024456
```

the error still remains.

```
%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE hr_dataset."Employee Number" = 1103024456

* postgresql+psycopg2://readonly:***@dsstudents.skillbox.ru:5432
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "Number"
LINE 1: ...ELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE hr_dataset.Employee Number = 1...
                                                             ^

[SQL: SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE hr_dataset.Employee Number = 1103024456]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

```
%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Employee Number" = 1103024456

* postgresql+psycopg2://readonly:***@dsstudents.skillbox.ru:5432/human_resources
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "Number"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE Employee Number = 1103024456
                                                ^

[SQL: SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE Employee Number = 1103024456]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

[Table definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWraG.png)

I'd like to use sql magic, is there some way to solve this?

Found the solution, just used triple quotes.

sqlalchemy 1.3.13
postgresql 12.2
psycopg2 2.8.6
ipython-sql 0.4.0

Comment: Add Jupyter tag to indicate where the sql magic is coming from. You should include that information in your question.

Comment: I cannot replicate. Can you show a complete example that includes setting up the connection using `%sql` and then doing `%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Employee Number" = 1103024456`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added information on connecting to the database. Or should I add a password so you can connect?

Comment: No that is not necessary. What is the table definition? Also can you run `%sql SELECT * FROM hr_dataset WHERE "Employee Number" = 1103024456` and return the error for that?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver done.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a way to show what I did for a similar situation. Though I could not replicate your error:

```
create table col_name_space(id int, "fld 1" varchar);
insert into  col_name_space values (1, 'test'), (2, 'dog'), (3, 'cat');

\d col_name_space 
                Table "public.col_name_space"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer           |           |          | 
 fld 1  | character varying |           |          | 

%load_ext sql 
%sql postgresql+psycopg2://aklaver:@localhost/test

%sql select * from col_name_space where "fld 1" is not null                                                                                                                                                              
 * postgresql+psycopg2://aklaver:***@localhost/test
3 rows affected.
Out[7]: [(1, 'test'), (2, 'dog'), (3, 'cat')]
```

As you can see double quoting the field name worked for me. In your case the double quoting is not being passed on to the query sent to the server. Not sure yet why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, just used triple quotes.

```
%sql select * from hr_dataset where """Employee Number""" = 1103024456
```